# How to insert dictionary at nsmutablearray index using loop

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

```
int a=0;
NSString *str;
str=txt_Field.text;
int n=[addArray count];
if (n==0)
{
    [addDic setObject:str forKey:@"name"];
    [addArray insertObject:addDic atIndex:0];
}
else
{
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        NSString *getString=[[addArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
        if (![str isEqualToString:getString])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            a++;
            NSLog(@" a>>>>  %d",a);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (a==0)
    {
        [addDic setObject:str forKey:@"name"];
        [addArray insertObject:addDic atIndex:i];
        NSLog(@" index >>>%d",i);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Name already exist...");
    }
}
NSLog(@"Array>> %@",addArray);
NSLog(@"Dictionary>> %@",addDic);
```

when i insert the name using textfield into the dictionary after that i insert it into the array index it's show last inserted value in the dictionary pls help me.

Comment: You are adding the same dictionary (`addDic`) time after time.  You need to create a new dictionary instance in each array element.

Comment: if i add 100+ object then i will create 100 instance how??????

Comment: Well I don't see where `addDic` is being created.  I also don't see how you add a new element to the array other than the very first element.

Comment: addDic is global which is created in .h file and alloc in viewdidload

Comment: So you agree with my first comment then?

Comment: How to create instance every time please give some hunt's

Comment: once check out my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
- (IBAction)saveText:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSDictionary * textDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_textField.text,@"name", nil];
    BOOL exist = NO;

    if (!textArray) // instance variable NSMutableArray * textArray;
    {
        textArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:textDic,nil];
        NSLog(@"first time");

    }
    else
    {
        for (NSDictionary * nameDic in textArray)
            if ([[nameDic objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:[textDic objectForKey:@"name"]])
             {
                    exist = YES;
                    break;
             }

        if (exist)
        {
            NSLog(@"name already existed");
        }
        else
        {
            [textArray insertObject:textDic atIndex:textArray.count];

            for (NSDictionary * nameDic in textArray)
                NSLog(@"saved names:%@",[nameDic objectForKey:@"name"]);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: How to show textArray data on tableview like if i insert data name=a,name=b,name=c...........then it should be show on table in same way name=a then in next cell name=b and so on..

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [[textArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: key should also be displayed on tableview here only one name key then the data should be displayed in the form like name=a then in next cell name=b and so on. = sign should be there on table view.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name = %@",[[textArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];

Comment: not static text if i change the key then this effect will be on table view

Comment: NSArray * keys = [textDic allKeys]; the array contain all keys in your dictionary,your dictionary have only one value so you can get that like this NSString * key = [[textDic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]; use that string to populate your cell label.